# Parameterized job always run with default parameter

Tags: jenkins

I am having troubles to force Jenkins job to always run with default parameter. Does anyone know the possible plugin to help with that case? Right now I am using extended parameter choice, but still there is no option to just run the job with default value without asking user for parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Currently there is not a straight forward solution to run a parameterized job with default parameter using a plugin. However there is a [workaround](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11851?focusedCommentId=230316&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-230316) to accomplish that using the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Plugin.

As @General_Code noted:

> Just add the build step, set the variable like: var1=value and then
>   use it using ${var1}

**Solution 2**

As @RejeeshChandran noted:
a more robust solution is the [Parameterized Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) which provides the functionality of **defaults values** for the parameters.

**Note**

*Note that [Parameter Defaults Options](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameter+Defaults+Options) is a plugin under development which will solve exactly this request. When it is released, you will be able to set it up so your parameter will get a default value when you run it manually.*

Comment: I found this plugin before. However for some reason I cannot find it in my extension setup.
EDIT: In the comments section it seems that this plugin hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for not verifying that before posting. It is still under development. However, they suggest a [workaround](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11851) using the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

Comment: I've used this workaround. For those interested: Just add the build step, set the variable like: `var1=value` and then use it using `${var1}`. Please edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sounds like a hack and not a viable solution for a large amount of build configurations.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this plugin [Parameterized Scheduler](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Scheduler+Plugin)

allow you to write a cron expression with the parameters inside like this

```
H(0-29)/10 * * * * % name=value; othername=othervalue
```

[Documentations](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: But will it allow me to run this job by user with default parameters? Or only when job is run by cron the default ones will be used?

Comment: it's allows you to Build periodically with parameters by cron with a default parameters see my request edited there are a document link

Comment: Correct scheduled tasks will pick the default value yet., but this is not relevant we're looking for an answer to a specific use case : "[..]here is no option to just run the job with default value without asking user for parameter"".

Answer (score 0):

Use `This build is parameterized` option in Jenkins configuration. Here you can add default values to the parameters. It will run with default value if the user doesn't change it. It is good to have configurable parameter before running the job.
[image]

For configuration details see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build. You can have multiple parameters.

Comment: As far as I know it does not help with the question "here is no option to just run the job with default value without asking user for parameter".

Answer (score 0):

Go to your jenkins job -> Configure -> General Tab

Add all options in "Description" but the default option in "Default Value"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIn4d.png)